# Start-Process to run a powershell script with switch parameters

Tags: powershell

What would be code to run a PowerShell script that includes a few switch parameters to be passed along with it and report success or failure?

```
Script Name : Get-Process.ps1
Switch Parameters :  -UseCached -RunReport -Silent
```

Normally I run it like

```
PS C:\DATA FOLDER\Javed Eqbal> .\Get-Process.ps1 -UseCached -RunRepor -Silent
```

I have the below code, but how do I include switch parameters in it?

```
$Exitcode = (Start-Process powershell -argument '.\Get-Process.ps1' -Wait -PassThru).ExitCode
if ($Exitcode = '0')
{
    Write-Host "SUCCESS"
}
else
{
    Write-Host "FAILURE"
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be a simple case of:

```
Start-Process powershell -argument '.\Get-Process.ps1 -UseCached -RunReport -Silent' -Wait -PassThru
```